# What is the easiest way to serialize and deserialize to XML

Tags: c#

```
class Server
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string AdminEmail { get; set; }
}
```

I need to serialize to XML and deserialize `List<Server> _servers`;

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class:

```
var servers = new List<Server>();
// fill servers...
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Server>));
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename))
{
     serializer.Serialize(writer, servers);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) to serialize

```
var serverInstances = new List<Server>(...);
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Server>));
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileFullName, FileMode.Create))
{
     serializer.Serialize(stream, serverInstances);
}
```

Comment: Marking the class as `Serializable` isn't necessary.

Comment: Don't forget there's `NonSerializedAttribute` for members you don't want to serialise. And `ISerializable` for finer control of the process.

Comment: almost but OP wants to serialize `List<Server>`

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: Interesting point regarding Serializable attribute... removed this point. thanks

Comment: As for the `Serializable` attribute, the `NonSerialized` attribute isn't involved in the XML serialization. For this purpose, `XmlIgnore` is the appropriate one.